# How can I load CSS only if a class is present on the page?

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to inject code for a platform I use with my clients on Cloudflare. I would like to be able to add the following CSS only IF the class: badge-icon.icon-template is NOT present. I would like to use javascript for this (I think this is the best solution). Can someone help?

```
Sorry there was more css. So I am not sure if this would work. .app-menu .app-menu_content .menu-items .menu-item.has-notifications .item-badge span, a.menu-item.menu-toggle.close.has-notifications, div.task-card_options {
display:none!important;
}
.tasks-page.has-task-page_right .tasks-page_body {
    padding-right: 0!important;
}
.task-page-container{
display:none!important;
}

#app-root > div.page > div > div.page-header > div.page-menu > div > a:nth-child(6){
display:none!important;
}

#app-root > div.app-menu > div.app-menu_content > div.main-menu > div > a:nth-child(7){
display:none!important;
}

#app-root > div.page > div > div.page-body.settings-page > div.settings-menu > div:nth-child(6), #app-root > div.page > div > div.page-body.settings-page > div.settings-content > div:nth-child(4), #app-root > div.page > div > div.page-body.settings-page > div.settings-menu > div:nth-child(2), #app-root > div.page > div > div.page-body.settings-page > div.settings-menu > div:nth-child(3){
display:none!important;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Create an array with the affected `elements`
- Check if there's an `element` with `.badge-icon` class name
- If not, get the `elements` from the `arr` and `style.display = "none"`

```
var arr = ['.app-menu', '.app-menu_content', '.menu-items', '.menu-item.has-notifications', '.item-badge span', 'a.menu-item.menu-toggle.close.has-notifications', 'div.task-card_options'];

if(!document.querySelector('.badge-icon')){
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        document.querySelector(arr[i]).style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

#### Edit:

In case you have many `styles` to apply, then you can *link* to a new **CSS File** in the `head` section, which will contain all the new styles. It'll override the current styles.

**Note**: change the folder path:

```
link_el.href = 'path/file.css';
```

```js
if(!document.querySelector('.badge-icon')){
    var link_el = document.createElement('link');
    link_el.rel = 'stylesheet';
    link_el.href = 'path/file.css';
    document.head.appendChild(link_el);
}
```

Comment: Sorry there was more css it didn't all copy over. So I am not sure if this would work.

Comment: Check the **Edit** section please

Answer (score 0):

```js
if (!document.getElementsByClassName("badge-icon")[0] && !document.getElementsByClassName("icon-template")[0]) {
  // inject code
}
```

This will inject the css if it cannot not find an element with any of the two class names above.

Answer (score 0):

1. Place an [IIFE (abbv. **I**mmediately **I**nvoked **F**unction **E**xpression)](https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-iife/) right before the closing `</body>` tag.
2. An IIFE will run immediately after the browser has parsed it so you'll want it positioned after everything in the `<body>` has been rendered by browser.
3. Assuming that the conditional CSS applies to the entire webpage (ie. `document` object), a `<style>` tag injected into the `<head>` as the last child element would be the most effective way.
4. The example below features an IIFE that once invoked will:

   1. pass 4 parameters (place as defined variables or the definition within the ***last set of parenthesis*** `(param1, param2, param3, param4)`):

      1. ***htmlString*** `String` representing the HTML to be rendered as real HTML

         ```
         const htmlString = `<style>`/* CSS styles here */`</style>`
         /* or if using an external stylesheet */
         const htmlString = `<link href="../path/to/style.css" rel="stylesheet">`
         ```
      2. ***selector*** `String` in CSS syntax of the element that needs to be present or absent

         ```
         ".badge-icon.icon-template"
         ```
      3. ***exist*** `Boolean`

         - `true` if presence of parameter #2 is needed
         - `false` if absence of parameter #2 is needed 
           in order for the CSS to be injected into the `<head>`
      4. ***node*** `DOM Object` that is searched, if not provided, default is `document`. Examples below are values other than `document`

         ```
         const node = document.querySelector(/*any CSS selector*/)
         /* or */
         const node = document.body
         ```

         ***Note:*** ***node*** is a single `DOM Object`
   2. then collect all elements that match ***selector***(#2) within the ***node***(#4) and get a count (referenced as ***target***)

      ```
      const target = node.querySelectorAll(selector).length;
      ```
   3. if ***exist***(#3) is `false` (in OP's case it is) then ***target*** should be 0 in order for the CSS to be injected. if ***exist*** is `true` then ***target*** must be greater than 0.

***Note:*** the selector `".badge-icon.icon-template"` will only target:

```
<anyTag class="badge-icon icon-template">...</anyTag>
```

but not the following:

```
<anyTag class="badge-icon">...</anyTag>
<!-- or -->
<anyTag class="icon-template">...</anyTag>
```

```js
const styleElement = `
   <style>
      body {
        background: black;
        color: lime;
        font: 4ch/1 Consolas;
      }
      article::before {
        content:'It works!'
      }
      .fail {
        display: none;
      }
     </style>`;

;((htmlString, selector, exist, node = document) => {
  let target = node.querySelectorAll(selector).length;
  if (target == exist) {
    document.head.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', htmlString);
  }
})(styleElement, ".badge-icon.icon-template", false);
```

```html
<article class='.badge-icon'>
  <p class='fail'>This doesn't work</p>
</article>
```